# complicated scanf conversion characters

Tags: c, scanf

I found such an example of scanf in C book (this time not K&R):

`scanf(" %[-' A-Za-z]s",&variable);`

Can anybody provide me with information what does it accept?
I have not found any info about using 'a' or 'z' as conversion characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the standard (C11, §7.19.6.2/12):

> `]` Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from a set of expected characters

That means that your format expects a run of of the characters `-`, space, `A`, ..., `Z`, `a`, ..., `z`.

The `[` conversion specifier has provisions for two special characters: `%[^...` *inverts* the matching set, and a hyphen (`-`) *between* two characters indicates a range, as is used in your `A-Z` and `a-z`.

Comment: Thank You!     So apparently I can use scanf("%[^\n]s", &var) to read spaces?

Comment: @PeterKowalski: Yeah... mind the stray `s`, though. That'll be expected literally, I think.

Comment: So what should I put instead of `s` ? I'm afraid I don't get the sentence "That'll be expected literally, I think"

Comment: @PeterKowalski: Nothing, just leave it out. You would need to have a literal 's' in your stream to match that. For example, `"%is%i"` would match `100s200`, and assign 100 and 200 respectively to the two variables.